# KeyError: -1 when appending new tag to soup in bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a template htm file with a table in it, which has one column and looks like this:

```html
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>ROWNAME1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>ROWNAME2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to create new td tags by iterating over the tr tags in the template and appending a new td inside every tr tag, so it will look like this, if I iterate over one of my input files:

```html
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>ROWNAME1</td>
   <td>ROWNAME1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>ROWNAME2</td>
   <td>ROWNAME2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

So, I'm basically copying the first td tag in a tr and appending it to the original template html. 
This happens by iterating over the rows (tr tags) of my template html. At each row, I fill the contents of a newly created td with the contents from a separate input file, which has a corresponding td tag with new information in it. The idea is to take a column from an input file and append it to the table in the template html. Each file I iterate over adds a new column to the table in the template.

This works fine for the first file. I can append the first new column to my template html no problem. But when I try to add the next column, the script throws the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Nothing\Henke Skripte\HTML_Tables_transform\Run\temp\Parameter_Tables.py", line 124, in content_replacer
    parent_tag.append(new_td)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 351, in append
    self.insert(len(self.contents), tag)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 315, in insert
    new_child.previous_element = previous_child._last_descendant(False)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 268, in _last_descendant
    last_child = last_child.contents[-1]
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 992, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: -1
```

Apparently, appending the new td works over 20 times, when I do it for the first column/input file. But directly when the next input file is used and I try to add the second column, a bs4 function tries to access the `attrs` dictionary of the newly appended td with the key "-1", which does not exist and I don't know why it would think that the key -1 should exist in the first place.

Here's my shortened code with an additional print of the td that causes the problem:

```py
def content_replacer(parent_tag,content,parent_html):

    '''Takes a td, replaces the content appropriately and returns it.'''

    html_content = BeautifulSoup(content,features='html.parser')

    # Go down the hierachy of children of td to create new td with the full formatting.
    td_tag = parent_tag.select('td')
    if len(td_tag) > 1:
        print(td_tag[0].prettify())
        print(td_tag[0].attrs)
    new_td = parent_html.new_tag('td', attrs=td_tag[0].attrs)
    parent_tag.append(new_td)


    p_tag = parent_tag.select('p')
    new_p = parent_html.new_tag('p', attrs=p_tag[0].attrs)
    new_td.append(new_p)

    span_tag = parent_tag.select('span')                    
    new_span = parent_html.new_tag('span', attrs=span_tag[0].attrs)
    new_p.append(new_span)

    new_span.contents = html_content



# mainloop over input files and tr tags.
all_input_files = glob('*.html')
htm_file = html_parser('template.htm')
nrows = len(htm_file.table.find_all('tr'))

row_name_cleaner = lambda tag: re.sub('[ ]{2,}',' ',tag.text.strip().replace('\n',''))

for i in range(len(all_input_files)):
    # html_parser just reads in htmls and turns them to soup.
    input_file = html_parser(all_input_files[i])
    # content_dictionary creates a dict of input data to be input into the new td tags
    content_dict = content_dictionary(input_file)
    for j in range(nrows):
        # get current row (tr tag)
        htm_row = htm_file.table.select('tr')[j]
        # Get info on current row.
        row_name = row_name_cleaner(htm_row)
        # Translate row name into slicing string for content_dict
        slice_string = slice_string_translator(row_name)
        # Get new content from input file
        new_content = content_dict[slice_string]
        content_replacer(htm_row,new_content,htm_file)
```

The print of the faulty td that is supposed to be appended looks like this:

```
<td style="width:163.55pt;border-top:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:none;
  mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-bottom-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:11.45pt" width="218">
 <p align="center" class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal">
  <span style='font-size:10.0pt;
  font-family:"CMU Serif"'>
   Compound
   <o:p>
   </o:p>
  </span>
 </p>
</td>

{'width': '218', 'style': 'width:163.55pt;border-top:solid windowtext 1.0pt;\n  border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:none;\n  mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-bottom-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;\n  padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:11.45pt'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Nothing\Henke Skripte\HTML_Tables_transform\Run\temp\Parameter_Tables.py", line 165, in <module>
    content_replacer(htm_row,new_content,htm_file)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Nothing\Henke Skripte\HTML_Tables_transform\Run\temp\Parameter_Tables.py", line 124, in content_replacer
    parent_tag.append(new_td)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 351, in append
    self.insert(len(self.contents), tag)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 315, in insert
    new_child.previous_element = previous_child._last_descendant(False)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 268, in _last_descendant
    last_child = last_child.contents[-1]
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 992, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: -1
```

Here's the full tr tag where the error occurs.

```html
<tr style="mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;height:11.45pt">
<td style="width:163.55pt;border-top:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:none;
  mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-bottom-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:11.45pt" width="218">
<p align="center" class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal"><span style='font-size:10.0pt;
  font-family:"CMU Serif"'>Compound<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td style="width:163.55pt;border-top:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:none;
  mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-bottom-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:11.45pt" width="218">
<p align="center" class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal"><span style='font-size:10.0pt;
  font-family:"CMU Serif"'>Compound<o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p align="center" class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal"><span style='font-size:10.0pt;
  font-family:"CMU Serif"'>PK59zni_co_100K_red</span></p></td></tr>
```

Comment: Can you try changing `new_td = parent_html.new_tag('td', attrs=td_tag[0].attrs)` to `import copy; new_td = copy.copy(td_tag)` and then append to parent_tag?

Comment: The error is the same. The second new td tag inside the tr tag is not appended, but I maybe the entire tr tag that fails might hold some answers so I'm gonna edit my post to provide it.

Comment: It's difficult to debug this for you, since you haven't created a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). `html_parser`, `content_dictionary` and `slice_string_translator` are missing.

Comment: I figured out how to provide all the necessary files for my script. My uni lets students upload files for a max of 90 days for downloading through url. This is the link:
https://depot.tu-dortmund.de/k77wu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me go first for the easy fix and then for the reason of the cryptic message, which hopefully is illuminating.

### Solution

In the line

```py
new_span.contents = html_content
```

replace it with

```py
new_span.contents = html_content.contents
```

Referring to the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children), the `contents` attribute is a list of children. By assigning it something that is not a list, the internal library code breaks the next time you come around. That's why it works for the first file but not the second.

In fact, it might be better to use

```py
new_span.append(html_content)
```

since it's more semantic and will take care of metadata. The library could take care of this with a setter but it doesn't seem to be the case.

### Why the cryptic message?

The following uses the code for **BeautifulSoup v.4.8.2**, particularly the file **`element.py`**.

Calling the `.append()` function is the same as inserting at the end of the structure.

```py
def append(self, tag):
  self.insert(position=len(self.contents), new_child=tag)

def insert(self, position, new_child):
  """Insert a new PageElement in the list of this PageElement's children.
     This works the same way as `list.insert`.
     :param position: The numeric position that should be occupied
        in `self.children` by the new PageElement. 
     :param new_child: A PageElement.
  """
  ...
```

Inside the `insert()` code, the `previous_child` object is, in our case, defined as the last structure in the `contents` list.

```py
previous_child = self.contents[position - 1]
```

Remember `new_child` is the new tag we're inserting. The next line is key

```py
new_child.previous_element = previous_child._last_descendant(False)
```

What this is doing is creating an attribute that refers to the *last descendant* of the previous child.

This can intuitively be seen for the following minimal example

```py
tree = BeautifulSoup(
  '<tr><td><p>string1</p><p><span>string2</span>string3</p></td></tr>',
  features='html.parser',
)
tree._last_descendant()  # 'string3'
```

Let us check then how `_last_descendant` is defined.

```py
def _last_descendant(self, is_initialized=True, accept_self=True):
  """Finds the last element beneath this object to be parsed."""
  ...
  while isinstance(last_child, Tag) and last_child.contents:
    last_child = last_child.contents[-1]
  ...
```

So the algorithm will roughly proceed as follows

```py
tree.contents
# [(Tag): <tr><td><p>string1</p><p><span>string2</span>string3</p></td></tr>]
tree.contents[-1]
# (Tag): <tr><td><p>string1</p><p><span>string2</span>string3</p></td></tr>
tree.contents[-1].contents
# [(Tag): <td><p>string1</p><p><span>string2</span>string3</p></td>]
tree.contents[-1].contents[-1]
# (Tag): <td><p>string1</p><p><span>string2</span>string3</p></td>
tree.contents[-1].contents[-1].contents
# [(Tag): <p>string1</p>, (Tag): <p><span>string2</span>string3</p>]
...
tree.contents[-1].contents[-1].contents[-1].contents[-1]
# 'string3'
# No longer an instance of Tag, but a NavigableString. Stop.
```

This assumes, rightfully so, that the `contents` attribute is always a list. The issue comes when it's not, getting you a `KeyError`.

Comment: Man, I even know that contents needs to be a list, but somehow since the first iteration worked, I'd have never thought to check that. Thank you very much, have all my karma.